# Functions Running Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, function, button

I have a function `buttonSwitch()` that is running at the incorrect times. I have a counter `count` and `cost` , the cost of buying an "upgrade". It functions normally at the beginning, the upgrade button's disabled until you have enough `count`, then you buy an upgrade, which pumps up the amount of `cost`, but the upgrade button only enables again once you have slightly more than `cost`. I am not entirely sure the reasoning for this but I suspect the reason is how the cost pumps itself up onclick.

Code : ( I apologize for the outrageous amount )

```
        let counterDisplayElem = document.querySelector(".points");
        let counterPlusElem = document.querySelector(".bigButton");
        let count = 0;

        function updateDisplay() {
            counterDisplayElem.innerHTML = "$" + Number(count.toPrecision(10));
        }

        updateDisplay();

       
        counterPlusElem.addEventListener("click", () => {
            count = count + 1;
            updateDisplay();
            buttonSwitch();
            

        function buttonSwitch() {
            if (count < cost) {
                buttonUpgradeElem.style.display = "none";
                buttonDisabledElem.style.display = "block";
            };
            if (count >= cost) {
                buttonUpgradeElem.style.display = "block";
                buttonDisabledElem.style.display = "none";
            };
        };
    // Upgrade button 1

        let buttonUpgradeElem = document.querySelector('.upGradeA.enabled');
        let cost = 20;
        let amount = 0;

        updateButtonDisplay();

        buttonUpgradeElem.addEventListener("click", () => {

            amount = amount + 1;            
            count = count - cost;
            buttonSwitch(); // disable button if you don't got the cash
            cost = Math.round(1.1 * cost); // Pump up the cost
            updateButtonDisplay(); // Now show the new cost
            updateDisabledDisplay(); // Update display of the disabled button
            updateDisplay(); // Update the rest
            if (audio2.paused === true) { // Play click sound
                play2();
            } else {
                audio2.pause();
                audio2.currentTime = 0;
                play2();
            };
            counterPlusElem.addEventListener("click", () => {
                count = count + 1;
                updateDisplay();
            });
        });



        function updateButtonDisplay() {
            buttonUpgradeElem.innerHTML = "Fingers | $" + cost + " | " + amount;
        };
    // Upgrade Button 1 - Disabled

        let buttonDisabledElem = document.querySelector('.upgradeA.Disabled'); // Disabled Button Element

        updateDisabledDisplay(); // Update the button's display on browser being opened

        function updateDisabledDisplay() {
            buttonDisabledElem.innerHTML = "Fingers | $" + cost + " | " + amount;
        }
```

Comment: Your code as posted seems to be missing a `}` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `buttonSwitch()` function and enabling/disabling the upgrade button is most likely due to the sequencing of operations in your code.

I've made the following adjustments to this revised version:

- The declaration and initialization of `buttonUpgradeElem` and `buttonDisabledElem` have been moved to the top of the file, with other variable declarations.
- At the beginning, the `updateButtonDisplay()` and `updateDisabledDisplay()` functions were called to ensure that the initial display of the buttons was right.
- The `counterPlusElem` (the button that increments the count) event listener has been moved to the top, outside the `buttonUpgradeElem` click event listener. This ensures that after each count increment, `buttonSwitch()` is performed, which updates the state of the upgrade button.
- Within the `buttonUpgradeElem` click event listener, a conditional check was added to verify that the button's functionality is only done when the count is higher than or equal to the cost.

The correct code is given below.

```java
let counterDisplayElem = document.querySelector(".points");
let counterPlusElem = document.querySelector(".bigButton");
let count = 0;
let buttonUpgradeElem = document.querySelector('.upGradeA.enabled');
let buttonDisabledElem = document.querySelector('.upgradeA.Disabled');
let cost = 20;
let amount = 0;

updateDisplay();
updateButtonDisplay();
updateDisabledDisplay();

counterPlusElem.addEventListener("click", () => {
    count = count + 1;
    updateDisplay();
    buttonSwitch();
});

buttonUpgradeElem.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (count >= cost) {
        amount = amount + 1;
        count = count - cost;
        cost = Math.round(1.1 * cost);
        updateButtonDisplay();
        updateDisabledDisplay();
        updateDisplay();
        if (audio2.paused === true) {
            play2();
        } else {
            audio2.pause();
            audio2.currentTime = 0;
            play2();
        }
    }
});

function updateDisplay() {
    counterDisplayElem.innerHTML = "$" + Number(count.toPrecision(10));
}

function buttonSwitch() {
    if (count < cost) {
        buttonUpgradeElem.style.display = "none";
        buttonDisabledElem.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        buttonUpgradeElem.style.display = "block";
        buttonDisabledElem.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function updateButtonDisplay() {
    buttonUpgradeElem.innerHTML = "Fingers | $" + cost + " | " + amount;
}

function updateDisabledDisplay() {
    buttonDisabledElem.innerHTML = "Fingers | $" + cost + " | " + amount;
}
```

Comment: Why would you call `Number()` on a `.toPrecision()` result when you're prepending a string (to a string)?